# Preventing the NoSuchElementException when reading from a file with no spare line

Tags: java, exception, variable-assignment

I am trying to find a way to deal with the NoSuchElementException error thrown by a Scanner object when reading the last item in my text file with NO SPARE LINE. This means that my cursor will end after the last character of the last line in the file

EXAMPLE:

score.txt

[Test;Word|]

[ & ] denotes the start and end of the text file

The | is where the cursor ends.

I know that if my cursor ends a line below it, my Scanner will not throw the NoSuchElementException because there is a nextLine.

What i want to achieve is to ensure that the NoSuchElementException is not thrown when the spare line is missing. Is there a way to prevent the error from occurring besides making sure that the spare line is there?

My Driver class simply calls the method importWordList() from class WordGame.

The code for WordGame is very long so I will only upload the method importWordList() from the class.

```
public boolean importWordList(String fileName) throws FileNotFoundException
{
    //Set default return value
    boolean returnVal = false;

    //Set File to read from
    File wordListDest = new File(fileName);

    if (wordListDest.canRead() == true)
    {
        lineS = new Scanner(wordListDest);

        //Read each line from file till there is no line
        while (lineS.hasNextLine())
        {

            //Set delimeter scanner to use delimeter for line from line scanner
            String line = lineS.nextLine();
            delimeterS = new Scanner(line);
            delimeterS.useDelimiter(";");

            //Read each delimeted string in line till there is no string
            while (delimeterS.hasNextLine())
            {

                //Store Variables for quiz object
                wordAndHint = delimeterS.nextLine();
                answer = delimeterS.nextLine();               //ERROR

                //Create Object Quiz and add to wordList
                Quiz addWord = new Quiz(wordAndHint, answer);
                wordList.add(addWord);
            }
            delimeterS.close();
        }
        lineS.close();
        returnVal = true;
        System.out.println("Word List has been Imported Successfully!");
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("The file path you selected either does not exist or is not accessible!");
    }
    return returnVal;
}
```

The Error that occurs is as Follows:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found
    at java.util.Scanner.nextLine(Scanner.java:1516)
    at mysterywordgame.WordGame.importWordList(WordGame.java:74)
    at mysterywordgame.Main.main(Main.java:60)
```

The error (at mysterywordgame.WordGame.importWordList(WordGame.java:74)) refers to line with the comment ERROR.

I have searched around for ways to prevent the error from occurring, however, all answers were "Make sure there is a spare line at the end of the text file"

Some help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you already consumed the next line with `wordAndHint = delimeterS.nextLine();` you have to check for next line again:

```
if(delimeterS.hasNextLine()){     
   answer = delimeterS.nextLine();     
}else{
   answer = "";
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much morja. This few lines of code solved a lot of issues.